# Library for sending video feedback to developer from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

If i recall correctly there used to be a third party library that upon device shake would allow the user to record the app ui and send feedback to the developers. Unfortunately my Google-fu is weak and i cant find it. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 5):

There are some tools that are exactly what you are looking at:

- Instabug (http://instabug.com)
- Flurry (http://www.flurry.com)
- Crashlytics (http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk/)
- Test Flight (https://www.testflightapp.com)
- PLCrashReporter (https://www.plcrashreporter.org/)
- BlitFeedback (http://www.blitfeedback.com)
- BugClipper (http://www.bugclipper.com)
- Glazum (https://www.glazum.com)
- Crittercism (http://www.crittercism.com)
- Tattle-UI-iOS (https://github.com/npctech/Tattle-UI-iOS)
- User Voice (https://www.uservoice.com/mobile/)
- AppHance (http://apphance.com)

That's all I know of at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it does video, but [Telerik's AppFeedback](http://www.telerik.com/appfeedback#shake-point-and-comment) does incorporate the shake gesture, and capture of screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, looks like an interesting alternative but im pretty sure there was one that does video so still looking for that one.